# Android studio @aar import creating incorrect exploded-aar directory

Tags: android, gradle, aar

So, here's the thing, I have a .aar file, and when i add it as a dependency as follows:

`compile('com.foo:bar:1.0.0@aar')`

It generates the following file:

`build > intermediates > exploded-aar > com.foo > bar > bar-1.0.0`

which contains the classes.jar, sources, etc.

However, it SHOULD be doing the following:

`build > intermediates > exploded-aar > com.foo > bar > 1.0.0`

Does anyone have any clue as to why my aar isn't being imported correctly?

This is a problem, as the following error occurs when building the gradle:

`com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.foo/bar/1.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)`

However, it is clearly visible in the `bar-1.0.0` directory.

Edit: more info

- Tested on 5 machines. All running AS 0.8.9, fresh install, fresh clone.
- Jdk 1.6 and 1.7 tested
- --refresh-dependencies called to make sure any changes have been collected

Nothing works.

Comment: Why does it matter what filename the build system uses in its intermediate output?

Comment: Updated question to explain why

Comment: Any chance you're running a very old version of the android-gradle plugin somewhere? I vaguely recall it used to unpack into the first naming convention for an intermediate directory, but that was a long time ago. I'm confused, though, because manifest merging is a more modern thing. I'm wondering if somehow you could have two versions of the plugin running.

Comment: How would I go about checking that? This is what is happening just from running a gradle sync on a brand new, fresh download of AS 0.8.9 and the newest gradle.

Comment: Attach your build files to your question.

Comment: Turns out, the minSDK wasn't installed. Sorry to waste your time. 

It took a while to come to that conclusion considering the manifestmerger was the error we got instead of the minSDK one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't going to answer my own question but I will now that I've received a few votes.

It turns out, the minSDK that was defined in my build.gradle wasn't installed.

Once I installed the proper SDKs, everything worked fine.